# Jquery ajax with JSON return can't access to data inside the JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

So I have this jquery code:

```
$(function(){
    var url = 'template/traitComTest.php';
    window.onload = function(e) {
        //  $(".formCom").ajaxForm({url: 'template/traitComTest.php', type: 'post'});
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data:  $( ".formCom").serializeArray(),
            success: function(reponse){
                console.log(reponse);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

with this php code:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST)) {
    $adresse = $_POST['adresse'];
    $com = $_POST['commentaire'];
    $sql = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE tempSelector_template SET commentaire= :com WHERE exemple = :exem ');
    $sql->execute(array(
        ":com" => $com,
        ":exem" => $adresse
    ));
    $myData1 = array('result' => $sql);
    echo json_encode($myData1);
    $sql->closeCursor();

    $sqlSelect = $bdd->prepare("SELECT commentaire FROM tempSelector_template WHERE exemple= :exemp");

    $sqlSelect->execute(array(
        ":exemp" => $adresse
    ));

    $myData = array('result1' => $sqlSelect);
    echo json_encode($myData);
}
```

I get this response from ajax on chrome' console =>

```
{"result":{"queryString":"UPDATE tempSelector_template SET commentaire= :com WHERE exemple = :exem "}}{"result1":{"queryString":"SELECT commentaire FROM tempSelector_template WHERE exemple= :exemp"}}
```

and my issue is that I can't access to the data inside the json and need your help

Comment: `JSON.parse(response);` is used to create objects out of JSON strings

Comment: Paste that whole response into a json validator. Will see that combining those two items is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you are basically returning 2 seperate sets of json encodes. It does not work that way. you can only accept a single set of json while reading through ajax. Not two. In your php script i see that you have included that following parts.

```
$myData1 = array('result' => $sql);
    echo json_encode($myData1);
```

and

```
$myData = array('result1' => $sqlSelect);

  echo json_encode($myData);
```

you should remove both parts and combine them into one single array using array_merge

```
$myData1 = array('result' => $sql);
$myData = array('result1' => $sqlSelect);
echo json_encode(array_merge(myData1,  $myData));
```

also in your ajax request, set dataType to json

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data:  $(".formCom").serializeArray(),
    success: function(reponse){
        console.log(reponse);
    });
```

Comment: thank you this work :) and i have one more question how can i put the content of my request into an html tag because right now i see the request but not the result of it?

Comment: @IZAD sure you can. just prepare the html in a variable and use jquery.append or jquery.html as you need.

Comment: @IZAD Also mark my answer as correct if it was. It will help stop inviting low quality answers. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems:

1. You are sending back invalid json: Instead of echoing out different json strings, you need to build a data-structure (an array or object) and only at the end encode and echo that once. Now you have concatenated json in your response and that makes it really hard to parse.
2. You are not parsing the json you get back in your javascript. When you return valid json (see 1.), you can add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax call to have jQuery parse the response automatically:

   `$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       dataType: 'json',
       url: url,
       // etc.`

Answer (score 0):

So you have a form and you want to submit and that ajax will return some data after submitting the form. And if you want to access the data of response. You need to add this things

1.) Add `type = 'post'` in your $.ajax object 
2.) And use `JSON.parse(response)`